# How to combine TypeScript constructor parameter properties with class inheritance and superclass constructor?

Tags: typescript

I understand that, in TypeScript, one can:

- [Declare class properties from the constructor declaration by using parameter properties.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html)
- [Inherit from a base class, in which case, the derived class constructor must call the base class constructor.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html)

Is it possible to combine these two behaviors? That is to say, is it possible to declare a base class which uses parameter properties, and then inherit from it in a derived class which also uses parameter properties? Does the derived class need to re-declare them, pass them into the superclass constructor call, etc.?

This is kinda confusing, and I can't figure out from the documentation whether this is intended to be possible, or -- if so -- how.

Thanks in advance if anyone has any insights into this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can combine the two, but from the point of the inheriting class the fields declared as constructor arguments will be regular fields and constructor arguments:

```
class Base {
    constructor(public field: string) { // base class declares the field in constructor arguments

    }
}

class Derived extends Base{
    constructor(public newField: string, // derived class can add fields
        field: string // no need to redeclare the base field
    ) {
        super(field); // we pass it to super as we would any other parameter
    }
}
```

**Note**

You can redeclare the field in the constructor argument but it will have to obey the rules for re-declaring fields (compatible types and visibility modifiers)

So this works:

```
class Base {
    constructor(public field: string) {

    }
}

class Derived extends Base{
    constructor(public field: string) { //Works, same modifier, same type, no harm from redeclration
        super(field);
    }
}
```

But this will not work :

```
class Base {
    // private field
    constructor(private field: string) {

    }
}

class Derived extends Base{
    constructor(private field: string) { //We can't redeclare a provate field
        super(field);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification!