# Effects of redeclaring TypeScript constructor parameter properties during class inheritance

Tags: typescript

This is a more theoretical question regarding what TypeScript does under the hood.

As specified in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51385400/how-to-combine-typescript-constructor-parameter-properties-with-class-inheritanc/) and based on personal experience, there are two ways of handling constructor parameter properties when inheriting from a class.

### Passing existing fields

```
class Base {
    constructor(public field: string) {}
}

class Derived extends Base {
    constructor(field: string) {
        super(field);
    }
}
```

### Redeclaring existing fields

```
class Base {
    constructor(public field: string) {}
}

class Derived extends Base {
    constructor(public field: string) {
        super(field);
    }
}
```

As per the linked question and answer, there are limitations to how the field can be redeclared, but those are clear to me.

My questions are the following:

- Does the second approach define two fields on the class, where the first is shadowed by the second? Would `this.field` and `super.field` evaluate to different attributes of the class?
- Similarly to the previous question, does the second approach behave differently with methods defined in the `Base` and `Derived` classes?

Ultimately it boils down to the question:
*Are these approaches functionaly identical, or do they behave differently in some edge-cases?*

Based on personal experience, the two approaches seem to do the same thing.

I would personaly go with the first approach, as I feel like "nothing can go wrong" and that there will be no hidden pitfalls with this approach, but I would like to understand this better, so that I don't base my programming decisions on vague feelings.

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by *"Similarly to the previous question, does the second approach behave differently with methods defined in the `Base` and `Derived` classes?"* Can you expand on that? What kind of difference are you thinking of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does the second approach define two fields on the class, where the first is shadowed by the second? Would `this.field` and `super.field` evaluate to different attributes of the class?

No. In JavaScript (and thus TypeScript), an object can only have a single property with any given name.¹ (The `super.x()` thing works with prototype methods because they're on the prototypes of the `Base` and `Derived` classes, not the object [instance].)

> Similarly to the previous question, does the second approach behave differently with methods defined in the `Base` and `Derived` classes?

I'm afraid I don't understand what you're asking there, but hopefully the following helps answer it.

The redeclaring version is problematic and I'd suggest not using it. To see why, let's look at the generated JavaScript for it (when targeting ES2015+):

```
class Base {
    constructor(field) {
        this.field = field;
    }
}
class Derived extends Base {
    constructor(field) {
        super(field);
        this.field = field;
    }
}
```

Notice how `Derived` passes `field` to `Base`, then **overwrites** the value `Base` may have set with its own `this.field = field` statement.

That's probably okay (but redundant) with the *specific* definition of `Base` you've shown, because all that `Base` does with its `field` parameter is the same assignment `Derived` does later. But it would be perfectly reasonable at some point for the author of `Base` to modify it slightly:

```typescript
class Base {
    public field: string;
    constructor(field: string) {
        this.field = field.trim(); // Or whatever
    }
}
```

Now, `Base` isn't just using `field` as-is, it's doing something to it before storing the result (trimming whitespace, in that example).

At this point, `Derived` breaks things, because `Base`'s work is thrown away and replaced by the `this.field = field` statement in `Derived`.

---

¹ That isn't true of some other languages. In Java, for instance, it's possible for one object to have more than one property with the same name declared by different classes in its hierarchy. Which one gets used depends on where the method using it is defined. But not in JavaScript or TypeScript.

Comment: Yes thank you for the answer. My OOP understanding comes from Java background so that was exactly what caused my confusion.

Comment: @Minop - I did much the same many, many years ago, and was similarly confused. :-) Beware that JavaScript's prototypical inheritance is *very different* from Java's class-based inheritance. Not worse or better, just quite different. The class-like trappings JavaScript has can sometimes give you the wrong impression.

Comment: @Minop - Similarly, there's a fundamental difference between TypeScript's type system and Java's: TypeScript's is *structural*, based on the shapes of types; Java's is *nominal*, based on the names (identities) of types. This is a more fundamental difference than it seems at first, so it's good to be aware of it. In TypeScript, it doesn't matter what the name or heritage of a type is; all that matters is the shape of the thing it describes. Example: https://tsplay.dev/wjnzvw

Comment: Here's an expanded version of that playground link: https://tsplay.dev/wepkVW

Comment: Thank you for the additional information! I am aware of the structural nature of the type system in TypeScript but it is always helpful to review it. The `instanceof C` example you gave surprised me at first, but it makes sense after a second look.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from looking at the compiler output. When redeclaring the field in the derived class, it just adds an additional assignment after calling the constructor of the base class. So if the passed value is modified in the `super` constructor that will be overwritten by the assignment.

```js
class Base {
    constructor(public field: string) { }
}

class DerivedOne extends Base {
    constructor(field: string) {
        super(field);
    }
}

class DerivedTwo extends Base {
    constructor(public field: string) {
        super(field)
    }
}
```

Output

```
var __extends = ...;

var Base = /** @class */ (function () {
    function Base(field) {
        this.field = field;
    }
    return Base;
}());

var DerivedOne = /** @class */ (function (_super) {
    __extends(DerivedOne, _super);
    function DerivedOne(field) {
        return _super.call(this, field) || this;
    }
    return DerivedOne;
}(Base));

var DerivedTwo = /** @class */ (function (_super) {
    __extends(DerivedTwo, _super);
    function DerivedTwo(field) {
        var _this = _super.call(this, field) || this;
        _this.field = field;   // Here the value gets assigned again
        return _this;
    }
    return DerivedTwo;
}(Base));
```